# How to rotate a widget many times?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rotation, widget, kivy

The official example from [here](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/examples/gen__canvas__rotation__py.html) shows how to rotate a widget **one time**:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv = '''
FloatLayout:

    Button:
        text: 'hello world'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
        canvas.before:
            PushMatrix
            Rotate:
                angle: 45
                origin: self.center
        canvas.after:
            PopMatrix
'''


class RotationApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)


RotationApp().run()
```

But if I want to create a rotation loop, ie, how to change the angle (and show the result) many times?

Comment: `angle = self.angle` then just update the angle in a Clock.schedule function ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make the amount of angle rotation a NumericProperty attached somewhere accessible (I attached it to app) then update it in a clock interval

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty

kv = '''
FloatLayout:

    Button:
        text: 'hello world'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
        canvas.before:
            PushMatrix
            Rotate:
                angle: app.angle
                origin: self.center
        canvas.after:
            PopMatrix
'''


class RotationApp(App):
    angle = NumericProperty(25)
    def build(self):
        def updates_spin(*args):
            self.angle += 2

        Clock.schedule_interval(updates_spin, 0.05)
        return Builder.load_string(kv)


RotationApp().run()
```

Comment: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html?highlight=properties#module-kivy.properties ... it just initializes it to 25...